# Is NetBeans not accepting _ide_helper from Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, netbeans, plugins

Using NetBeans 8.2 with Laravel, I'm setting the _ide_helper.php to my project as described in his link https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper,
it was set on terminal the command

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

then after, it was added into config/app.php the line

```
Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
```

and for last, the command on the project folder

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

but nothing has changed apparently. No auto complete, no references. Here are some images comparing what is expected and what is happening.

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1EdS.png)

[Happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3RLO.png)

Plus, NetBeans is marking an error inside the ide_helper file which confuses the syntax by the name of the function ('if'). I'll put an image of the part showing the error

[Error_NetBeans_ide_helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB4xc.png)

I've rebooted NetBeans, tried downloading and setting directly the file, but no lucky. Is the function 'if' causing the problem? Or is NetBeans not accepting the _ide_helper?

Comment: I have the same problem. I've tried apache netbeans 10.0 as well, but no luck. My biggest issue is with the generated helper file for models, that should add all your model scopes, but it does not. It works in PHP Storm, but that has other issues I cannot work with...